# How to makes Activiti run multiple parallel process instances

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I have a Spring Boot web application project using an embedded Activiti engine (using the activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic Maven dependency) with a simple workflow processing a business request. There are service tasks implemented with JavaDelegate objects.

We may have multiple parallel requests that must be processed at the same time. However, the Activiti engine is waiting for a given process instance to reach a pause state (waiting for messages) before beginning a new process instance.

We are starting a process instance using this command :

```
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("process_simple", variables);
```

I have added to application.properties the following to no use :

```
# Activiti config
spring.activiti.jobExecutorActivate = true
spring.activiti.asyncExecutorEnabled = true
spring.activiti.asyncExecutorActivate = true
```

I also have define all service tasks to Asynchronous, and to Multi-instance type : parallel but that does not work either.

Have I missed a setting ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are those tasks from the same process instance ?

Comment: They all use the same process definition, but a new process instance is launched each time with the runtime service.

Comment: it will be helpful if we could see the process definition xml file

Comment: @Kamalen, we are also facing the exact issue and in our case the total process would take about few minutes to few hours... can you pls let me know if your issue was resolved and what was the change?